# Determine the number of terms by year in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, filter, count, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have two tabs in my Google Sheets file.
One of these tabs contains our guests' data.

[image: datas]

The other is a summary of payment methods by years.

[image: Summarise]

Could you explain me, how can I fill in the summary cells with the datas from the other tab?

Thank you!

Comment: can you share a copy / sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PsyOSq-DdhZkUUFRO3Rx0eJZLwfniggan7-LpFPF9Zo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula in cell B3 and expand over the other cells:

```
=count(filter(Adatok!$C:$C;year(Adatok!$D:$D)=B$2;Adatok!$E:$E=$A3))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({Adatok!A2:E}; 
 "select Col5,count(Col2) 
  where Col5 is not null 
  group by Col5 
  pivot year(Col4)
  label Col5'Payment method'")
```

[image]